# Spin dependence of particle decay

Tags: special-relativity, bosons

I was wondering

> How does the spin of a decaying particle influence the kinematics of the decay?

For example: I know that for a spin-0 particle decay such as

$$ \pi^0 \rightarrow \gamma\gamma $$

the angular distribution in the center of mass frame of the photons is uniform since the particle has spin-0.

But in the case of the following decay (which is the one i'm interested in)

$$ Z \rightarrow e^+ e^- $$

how can I evaluate the angular distribution of the electrons?

Comment: To answer that, readers need to know how much quantum field theory you understand. Have you computed other Standard Model processes using Feynman rules?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, i know basic QFT, i've just followed two courses: relativistic quantum mechanics, where we calculated some basic second order processes in QED, and an elctroweak course which went much more into details. In that we calculated muon decay, Z decay and some others

Comment: I don't want to say that i'm an expert but i should understand QFT calculations

Comment: If you already computed one Z decay channel, can’t you adapt that calculation to this one? (I’m not hiding the answer; I don’t know the answer. I just know that this approach should be able to give you the answer.)

Comment: @G.Smith yes, I was thinking about that but at the moment I'm not very sure on how to do it

Comment: You can see the angular distributon data from LEP report at page 55 here  https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ex/0509008.pdf there is  a reference to standard model fit

Comment: @annav I'm not sure that answers my question or how since that's the differential cross section for the $e^+ e^- \rightarrow e^+ e^-$ process

Comment: @DavideMorgante  It is on the Z pole, that is what you are asking. Zs are not stable particles, are only  as resonances , in this paper seen in the scattering crossection, and the result of their decay in an LHC reaction should be  the same . Anyway if I had an answer I would write it out. It is just for information.